# What is the difference between "Como estas" and Como estás"

Tags: gramática

What is the difference between `Como estas` and `Como estás` with an accent??? Does it mean something else???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C**ó**mo estás is:

"how" + the informal conjugated form of estar; the unshortened phrase is ¿Cómo estás tú? Note the accent in "cómo¨ which is placed due to this being a question.

"How are you?"

===========================================================

Como estas is:

"how/like" + "these"   ... followed by a feminine plural object. (Likewise for example, como este would be "how this" followed by a masculine singular noun.)

So this would be part of a larger sentence typically.

===========================================================

Also, with the accent like so:

como éstas   <-------- "how/like" + "these", same as above, except éstas with the accent is a pronoun and stands in for the object

Answer (score 8):

First of all, I'd like to say that it'd be better if you write the whole sentences, just to get the context.

However, I'll try to translate them both literally:

> 1. Como éstas => like these ones
>
>    Ex: Yo también tengo unas zapatillas como éstas.
> 2. Como éstas => eat these ones
>
>    Ex: Tú te comes esas patatas, yo me como éstas.
> 3. ¿Cómo estás? => How are you? (You have to write the graphic accent
>      since it's a question)
> 4. Como estas => like these
>
>    Ex: Tus pulseras son tan bonicas como estas diademas.

Comment: 5. Como estás => how you are

Comment: Be aware that, according to current ortography rules, writing *éstas* is no longer recommended. Cases 1. and 2. should be *Como estas*.

Comment: I agree with serfe 100% I'm not up-to-date on the rules of the Royal Academy of the Spanish language, but it makes sense to differenciate using the accent mark in serfe's second example.

Comment: Great anwser and <3 "bonicas" xD (I guess i can "xD" instead of "lol" here :D)